# Entity Framework Core tricky mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a following table stored in a Microsoft SQL Server database. Please note that this is a denormalized table coming from another system so I can't change this:

```
CREATE TABLE Request 
(
    RequestId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RequestName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    RequestProperty1 varchar(30) NULL,
    RequestProperty2 varchar(30) NULL,
    RequestProperty3 varchar(30) NULL
)
```

And I have defined following corresponding entity class for it:

```
public class Request
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> requestProperties;

    [Key]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string RequestName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> RequestProperties { get => requestProperties; set => requestProperties = value; }
}
```

How do I write C# Entity Framework Core to read and write data from the `Request` table using the entity class `Request`?

Please note that the `Request` class does not have corresponding fields for table columns `RequestProperty1`, `RequestProperty2` and `RequestProperty3`; rather it stores the values for these columns in a `RequestProperties` dictionary, with column name as key and column value as value.

Only way I think of adding three more protected fields on `Request` class for `RequestProperty1`, `RequestProperty2` and `RequestProperty3`, then map them to the dictionary property `RequestProperties` while reading/saving to database but this means that I have double storage of these fields once in actual protected fields and once in the dictionary so not an optimized solution.

I have thousand of records in database table so want to optimized the reading/saving more efficient.

I tried various solution which works both for reading and saving and solution seems to inefficient

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#configuring-indexer-properties